# npm : i mis-typed a command "npm ls -g -depth=0" as "npm ls -g -d=0" and it's been executed

Tags: node.js, npm, command, alias

I thought the option "-depth=0" could also be done as "-d=0" and it's been executed. But the result isn't what I expected. I've searched for a long time to see what I've just done, but no clue. What does that command mean?

```
C:\Users\Sam>npm ls -g -d=0

npm info it worked if it ends with ok

npm info using npm@6.10.3

npm info using node@v10.15.1

C:\Users\Sam\AppData\Roaming\npm

`-- (empty)

npm timing npm Completed in 1821ms

npm info ok

C:\Users\Sam>npm -d -h

npm info it worked if it ends with ok

npm info using npm@6.10.3

npm info using node@v10.15.1

Usage: npm <command>

where <command> is one of:
    access, adduser, audit, bin, bugs, c, cache, ci, cit,
    clean-install, clean-install-test, completion, config,
    create, ddp, dedupe, deprecate, dist-tag, docs, doctor,
    edit, explore, get, help, help-search, hook, i, init,
    install, install-ci-test, install-test, it, link, list, ln,
    login, logout, ls, org, outdated, owner, pack, ping, prefix,
    profile, prune, publish, rb, rebuild, repo, restart, root,
    run, run-script, s, se, search, set, shrinkwrap, star,
    stars, start, stop, t, team, test, token, tst, un,
    uninstall, unpublish, unstar, up, update, v, version, view,
    whoami

npm <command> -h  quick help on <command>
npm -l            display full usage info
npm help <term>   search for help on <term>
npm help npm      involved overview

Specify configs in the ini-formatted file: C:\Users\Sam\.npmrc

or on the command line via: npm <command> --key value

Config info can be viewed via: npm help config

npm@6.10.3 C:\Users\Sam\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm
```

Comment: I was kinda worried if that "-d" could be something like "delete". But I can't see any difference in my files at "Users\Sam\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\" directory.

Comment: looks like -d=0 flag is when you want to log node and npm versions only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-d` is a shortcut for `--loglevel info`.

You can find the information on this page https://github.com/npm/cli/blob/latest/doc/misc/npm-config.md#shorthands-and-other-cli-niceties